# How to get each UID from where I'm clicking

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a little problem, each time I want to set a new value to a desired user under my adminUID I dont know how to set the value to that current user since I dont have the UID of that user

Database Structure

[image]

I can bring to my app the users who pregunta is 1 or 0 and make the switch enabled or not, thats right

[image]

But I need when I click the switch to change that value from 0 if pregunta = 1 or to 1 if pregunta = 0 . I managed to do that in this way in my adapter

```
  holder.mSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(modelArrayList.get(position).getPregunta()==1){

                    mDatabase.child("myapp").child(adminID).child("users").child(userID).setValue(0);

                }else if (modelArrayList.get(position).getPregunta()==0){
                    mDatabase.child("myapp").child(adminID).child("users").child(userID).setValue(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now what I want is to get the `.child(userID)` from where I click the switch in order to update that certain user.

Edit:

I came up with this idea

```
 for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                               String key = snapshot.getKey();
                               UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                               String nombrePaciente = userModel.getNombre();

                               if(nombrePaciente.equals(modelArrayList.get(position).getNombre())){

                                   mDatabase.child("myapp").child(adminID).child("users").child(key).child("pregunta").setValue(0);

                               }

                           }
```

it is working but if I have 2 users with the same name it will modify it for the two of them, I was thinkin in store inside each user their own user id and compare that uid with the UID of the key of that user, that will do the job, but, **is there an efficient way to do this**?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Stored the uid of each user when I created them in my model array and then just compared it

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                               String key = snapshot.getKey();

                               if(key.equals(modelArrayList.get(position).getUid())){

                                   mDatabase.child("myApp").child(adminID).child("users").child(key).child("pregunta").setValue(0);

                               }

                           }
```